# npm install not compiling forked material-ui src into lib folder

Tags: git, npm, npm-install, git-fork

I am using material-ui in my app. I forked material ui and rolled back to pervious version and made some changes there, now I want to use the forked repo in my project so I used the following steps to install module from [here](https://coderwall.com/p/q_gh-w/fork-and-patch-npm-moduels-hosted-on-github):

1. Go to `fork's` page
2. Go to `commits`
3. On the right side of the `commit` you want to use click `Browse code`
4. On the browse code page right-click on `Download ZIP` button (or whatever it is that you are seeing) and copy . It should be something like this

> https://github.com/SoftwareMarbles/express-jsend/archive/fdd4089087d916fa6e3b5abaa1ff9dd9ea96df8d.zip

5. Edit that URL replacing `archive` with `tarball` and removing the `.zip` extension. You should end up with something like

> https://github.com/SoftwareMarbles/express-jsend/tarball/fdd4089087d916fa6e3b5abaa1ff9dd9ea96df8d

6. Paste that into your package.json instead of the version. Like this:

`"express-jsend": "url/from/step/5"`

`npm install` runs successfully without giving any errors but it does not compile the `js` files in `src` and put them in `lib` folder as compare to when i run npm install with following code in my package.json

`"material-ui": "0.14.4"`

So my question:

***Why is npm not compiling the src files and putting them in lib folder?***

Answer (score 3):

The reason pointing directly to your fork of the [callemall/material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) repo does not work is that the package in the root of that repo is only for *building* the material-ui package that gets published to npm.  Note that the name in the [root package.json](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/package.json) is "material-ui-build" -- not "material-ui".

The actual material-ui package is created by running `npm run build` in the root of the repo. This writes the material-ui package to the `build` subdirectory of the repo root.

If you want to point to your github fork of material-ui in the dependencies section of your `package.json`, you could create a new repo containing the contents of the `build` subdirectory and point your `package.json` to that new repo (cumbersome).  Like this:

```
git clone git@github.com:callemall/material-ui.git material-ui
cd material-ui
npm install
npm run build
cp -Tr build ../material-ui-package
cd ../material-ui-package
git init .
git add .
git commit -m ...
```

An alternative to pointing to a custom github repo would be to publish a scoped package to npm (I have never done this).  Or if you are only doing local development, you could use `npm link` to point your package to the `material-ui/build` subdirectory.