# npm install a forked branch

Tags: github, npm-install

I've gone through several threads on this topic but still having a problem with installing a specific fork of a GitHub repo.

I've forked `mui-org/material-ui` to `myuser/material-ui`. To install the fork in my main project, I ran the following command:

`npm install --save myuser/material-ui`

This added a line `"material-ui-workspace": "github:myuser/material-ui",` in my package.json file. Under the node_modules, I see a folder `material-ui-workspace` with contents of the forked repo, but not the actual build files. Where is this `-workspace` coming from?

To address this, I ran `npm run build` in the forked repo and committed the build folder back to the repo. Then I ran the same npm install command again, but nothing changed.

What exactly do I need to do in order to install this forked repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/41058940/735310

I ended up creating a new repo `material-ui-package` with just the contents of the `build` folder and then deployed it using:

`npm install --save myuser/material-ui-package` and it worked.

It's quite cumbersome indeed. If there's a better approach, please let me know.

The name `material-ui-workspace` was coming from the package.json of the master branch of the forked folder.